# Is this a correct identity for the Kronecker delta and the Alternating Tensor?

Tags: notation, vectors, vector-analysis, cross-product

If $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is the alternating tensor and $\delta_{in}$ is the Kronecker delta, am I correct in thinking that
$$
\delta_{in}\varepsilon_{ijk} = \varepsilon_{ink}
$$

If not, what is the correct evaluation of this expression?

Many thanks

Comment: You can think of $\delta_{in}$ as being a function which converts $i$'s to $n$'s or $n$'s to $i$'s (depending on which is being summed over).  So the formula should be $$\delta_{in}\epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{njk}$$

Comment: I'm not that well-versed in tensor-notation, but as far as I remember, anything that appears in the index twice (the $i$) is summed over and will therefore not be appearing on the RHS.

Comment: @user2910074 If I've answered your question make sure you remember to click the checkmark left of my answer (it'll turn green once you do).  If not, what should I expand on?

Comment: It was perfect, thanks. Never realised it was possible to check mark a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is $$\delta_{in}\epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{njk}$$

One way to know that your proposed formula is wrong is to consider what *type* of index each of the four are.  $i$ appears twice so it is a **summing index**.  Thus it shouldn't appear on the other side (unless it happens to be a summing index on the other side of the equation as well).  But $n$, $j$, and $k$ only appear once each.  Thus they are **free indices**.  That means that *must* appear on both sides of the equation.

Here's something interesting: That product comes up when deriving the relationship between the triple scalar product and the $3\times 3$ determinant: $$\begin{align}a\cdot (b\times c) &= a_n\mathbf e_n\cdot \epsilon_{ijk}b_jc_k\mathbf e_i \\ &= a_n\epsilon_{ijk}b_jc_k\mathbf e_n\cdot\mathbf e_i \\ &= a_n\epsilon_{ijk}b_jc_k\delta_{ni} \\ &= \delta_{ni}\epsilon_{ijk}a_nb_jc_k \\ &= \epsilon_{njk}a_nb_jc_k \\ &= \det(a,b,c)\end{align}$$